# Are complete sufficient statistics unique?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

I'm under the impression that up to a one-to-one function complete sufficient statistics are unique. How can I show this?

Comment: see [What are complete sufficient statistics?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41881/what-are-complete-sufficient-statistics/41938#41938)   and    [What is the intuition behind defining completeness in a statistic as being impossible to form an unbiased estimator of 0
from it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196601/what-is-the-intuition-behind-defining-completeness-in-a-statistic-as-being-impos)