# How do I interpret the completeness in Statistics in practice?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, complete-statistics

I'm aware of the mathematical definition of complete statistics, but I'm pretty confused about what does the completeness really mean. It would be better to have a practical example from you guys.

Regards,
Li

Comment: What you are looking for is a complete sufficient statistic.  Look into Lehmann's Testing Hypotheses book.

Comment: See also [What is the intuition behind defining completeness in a statistic as being impossible to form an unbiased estimator of 0
from it?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/196601/17230).