# intuition/explanation for "Hausman's result"?

Tags: hausman

Greene (econometric analysis p. 235 7th ed) discusses the Hausman test (test for whether the OLS is consistent). Greene states:

> [image]

Probably, Greene believes that Hausman's technical statement of this result is too difficult for his readers. **I nevertheless would like an intuition of why the covariance term would be zero, because it is not at all intuitive to me**, especially that the efficiency has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, if it was not zero, the efficient estimator could be made more efficient by exploiting that non-zero correlation.

Comment: How could it be exploited?

Comment: @Programmer2134 By making the variance smaller.

Comment: By definition of inefficiency we can make the variance smaller, but I meant how could we do that.

Comment: @Programmer2134 By combining it with an estimator that is unbiased estimator of zero. There's a nice proof with some intuition [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/196996/7071).